# Common law spouse

Tags: visas

I live in Jamaica with my common law spouse. I have my B1/B2 visa and my spouse would like to try for his visa too. Can he get his visa too as if we were legally married? Please explain what are his chances of getting the visa being that i have mine and live in the same household?

Comment: To answer your question we do need at least both nationalities, the country or countries you want to travel to, the duration of stay there and any details you feel are notable about your situation.

Comment: Since the OP mention a "*B1/B2"* visa, we might reasonably assume travel is to the US, for a duration in keeping with that visa.  But we definitely need the other details, and confirmation of my assumptions at the same time would be good.